# Token Storage Problems Symfony 5 Custom Login Authenticator

Tags: symfony, security, authentication, session, controller

When the user logs in to the system, I need to fill a class variable (Login-> testInfo) with information, but in the controller the variable always returns null.

Here is a generic example.

The Login class

```
class Login extends UserInterface
{

    private $testInfo = null;

    public function setTestInfo(string $testInfo)
    {
        $this->testInfo = $testInfo;
    }

    public function getTestInfo() : ?string
    {
        return $this->testInfo;
    }
}
```

The Authenticator:

```
class FormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{

...
    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
         $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Login::class)->findByUsername(credentials['username']);

        if (!$user)
        {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Username could not be found.');
        }

        //this prints NULL
        dd($user->getTestInfo());

        $user->setTestInfo('testing the string');

        //this prints 'testing the string'
        dd($user->getTestInfo());

        return $user;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        //this prints 'testing the string'
        dd($token->getUser()->getTestInfo());
    }

...

}
```

The Controller Class:

```
class MyController extends AbstractController
{

    private $login = null;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->login = $tokenStorage->getToken() ? $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser() : null;
    }

    public function home()
    {
        //this prints null
        dd($this->login->getTestInfo());
    }
}
```

If $user goes to the tokenStorage with the new value ('testing the string'), why, when I try to use it on the controller, does the variable always return null? what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is `testInfo` a transient variable? Because you gotta know that there is [`UserProvider`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#creating-a-custom-user-provider) that tries to refresh user from token (maybe it could be "changed" somehow between requests). I'm pretty sure you're losing those infos right in this process.

Comment: yes. i maked a complete debug and this is my conclusion too. however, i solved the problem using the EquatableInterface. i'm happy now! thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your controller constructor isn't being executed too soon, prior to the authentication success event writing the token to the token storage service? I'd `dd()` the token in the constructor to verify if the token and Login instance are present at that point.

You may need to use `setContainer()` instead of `__construct()` in your controller to retrieve the authenticated token, which would look something like this:

```
private $tokenStorage   = null;
private $login          = null;

public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}

/**
 * @param  ContainerInterface      $container Symfony service container interface
 * @return ContainerInterface|null
 */
public function setContainer(\Psr\Container\ContainerInterface $container): ?\Psr\Container\ContainerInterface
{
    if ($this->tokenStorage instanceof TokenStorageInterface && $this->tokenStorage->getToken() instanceof TokenInterface && $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser() instanceof Login) {
        $this->login = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    }

    return $container;
}
```